# ConvertNumber do JSF negative values

Tags: jsf, converters, currency, negative-number

The negatives monetaries values, when i use the JSF's native conversor, `<f:convertNumber type="currency"/>`, keeps the character '`-`' before the currency symbol.

For example: `-$ 56.134.726,99`

.xhtml

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{entity.monetaryValue}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Is there any solution to this problem different from creates my own Converter?

Comment: What actually is the problem ? Do you want to skip the minus sign completely ? Or mayby do you want to print it in another place, for example after `$`,  not before ?

Comment: i wanted `$ -56.134.726,99` instead `-$ 56.134.726,99`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" locale="DE" 
      pattern="¤###,###,##0.00;¤-###,###,##0.00"    />
```

The pattern is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Note: I use `locale="DE"` because in this locale `,` is used as decimal separator, and `.` as group separator.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `Converter` and override `getAsString()` method as:

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null)
                return "";
    return "$"  + String.valueOf(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(value));
}
```

Comment: "Is there any solution to this problem different from creates my own Converter?"

Comment: I had this problem and only solution I ever got was the one above.

Comment: nice!! but, using the `pattern ` passed in the other answer worked.